# Selecting every 3 seconds data rows between 2 dates

Tags: oracle, date

I have a requirement to take every 3 seconds data within the specific time interval in SQL. I am new to SQL so can anyone help me on the scenario
This is my select query which returns all the values but i need data for every 3 seconds only

```
SELECT ton_nbr 
FROM 
    icr_file_interface 
WHERE 
    (
        reading_dttm BETWEEN
        TO_DATE(concat('2016-10-19',to_char(0930)),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISS')
        AND TO_DATE(concat('2016-10-19',to_char('0945')),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISS')
    )
    AND
    (
        ton_nbr BETWEEN 
        (SELECT value FROM text_para WHERE para_cd='ICR_ST_RNG') 
        AND (SELECT value FROM text_para WHERE para_cd='ICR_ED_RNG') 
    )
```

Comment: please write your sql query  properly, within a code sample.

Comment: I already proposed an edit. Waiting for approval.

Comment: is this Oracle (`TO_DATE`)

Comment: Thanks for the editing I am new to this.Yes oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This selects you data between last 3 seconds. Hope you got the idea.

```
select ton_nbr 
from   icr_file_interface 
where  reading_dttm between dateadd(ss, -3, getdate()) and getdate() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply.any oracle equivalent for the dateadd function?

Comment: @naveena oh, this is now in Oracle tag, sorry, I don't know, I Am using SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to subtract 3 seconds from a date, you can use the following:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  2         to_char(sysdate - 3*1/24/60/60, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  3  from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3*1
------------------- -------------------
2016-10-19 09:38:17 2016-10-19 09:38:14
```

Given that `sysdate -1` means "subtract one day to sysdate", you can derive the number of seconds you need with a bit af arithmetic

Comment: Thanks for your time. I need every 3 seconds data for a specific time interval.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. What do you mean with "every 3 seconds"? Do you need a procedure that runs every 3 seconds? or a single query that returns data in the last 3 seconds? Please post some sample data and desired result to clarify the question

Comment: My table will have each second data ex. 7/12/2016 12:11:43 AM 4961.31 
7/12/2016 12:11:42 AM 4961.31 
7/12/2016 12:11:41 AM 4961.31 
7/12/2016 12:11:40 AM 5000.20 in this my select query should select only 7/12/2016 12:11:43 AM & 7/12/2016 12:11:40 AM with in a specific time say 7/12/2016 12:10:00 AM to 7/12/2016 12:12:00 AM

Comment: If you have a row for each second, in tha time interval you will have much more results, am I wrong? Please edit your question, with sample data, trying to better explain your need,do no add comments